# Sorting 2 related arrays

Tags: sorting, rust

I have two vectors

```
let mut ratings = vec![2000.0, 2012.0, 2390.0, 1234.0];
let mut ids = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
```

Where ids[n] corresponds ratings[n] and i want to sort ratings vector by asc, so that ids vector changed with ratings.

Expected output

```
assert!(ratings == vec![1234.0, 2000.0, 2012.0, 2390.0]);
assert!(ids == vec![4, 1, 2, 3]);
```

I haven't found solution for vec sort function.

Comment: You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69764256/8564999) to get sorting indices. But the fact that `ratings` contains floats will make it difficult, because `f32` doesn't implement `Ord` trait

Comment: Maybe you are using wrong data-structure. Do you need ratings and ids in separate lists? If you could merge them this would be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

You can zip the two vectors together, then sort, then unzip:

```
let mut zipped: Vec<_> = ratings.into_iter().zip(ids).collect();
zipped.sort_unstable_by(|(a, _), (b, _)| a.total_cmp(b));
(ratings, ids) = zipped.into_iter().unzip();
```

You can avoid reallocating the two original vectors if you `drain()` them instead of consuming them:

```
let mut zipped: Vec<_> = ratings.drain(..).zip(ids.drain(..)).collect();
zipped.sort_by(|(a, _), (b, _)| a.total_cmp(b));
let mut unzipped = (ratings, ids);
unzipped.extend(zipped);
(ratings, ids) = unzipped;
```

To make use of the `Extend<(A, B)>` implementation for pairs of the form `(impl Extend<A>, Extend<B>)`, we first need to move `ratings` and `ids` into a pair, and then we need to move them back out again to get them back. Unfortunately, there is no `impl<A, T: Extend<A>> Extend<A> for &mut T`; if there were, we could use `(&mut ratings, &mut ids).extend(zipped)` instead of the last three lines.

(Note that the code was intentionally written to not rely on the `Copy` or `Clone` traits for the elements of the original vectors. We don't really need them, so I chose to write the more generic version.)

Comment: Definitely the simplest method, if performances are not too much of a concern (as it allocates 3 vectors). It might also be possible to create a vector of indexes, sort that (to get the permutations) then apply that but I'm not sure how easy it is, as applying the permutations would be scrambling the existing vector. The third option would likely be to hand-sort so you can apply the permutations manually (I don't think rust exposes the permutation operation, I guess that's an advantage of Go's old non-generic sort mess, since you needed to swap yourself you could swap across multiple slices).

Comment: @Masklinn Applying the premutation without allocating is definitely going to be a pain. In my opinion, the right solution is to skip the last step (unzipping), because the data should be much more usable in that format anyway.

Comment: Good point, you could probably `copied()` the source iterators rather than consume them, then overwrite the input vectors with the sorted value, only allocates one intermediate vector which is pretty good.

Comment: @Masklinn Good idea! It's even possible to `drain()` the vectors, since `Vec` guarantess that it will never automatically shrink. I added example code to the answer. The unzipping is slightly more convoluted than it could be, but it's still nice enough.

Comment: Oh smart call on the drain, I usually forget it's available to move things out of a collection without moving the collection. Also had no idea `Extend` was implemented on 2-uples, that's real cool.